# How to make nginx proxy according to url parameters？

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-location, proxypass, nginx-config

I want to make nginx proxy according to url parameters

url example:
www.foo.com/proxy/$serverUrl/$picUrl

$serverUrl example: storage.example.com
$picUrl example: test.jpg or test.png

proxy to:
https://$serverUrl/static/$picUrl

how to make nginx proxy like that?

Answer (score 1):

```
location ~ /proxy/(.*)/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass https://$1/static/$2;
}
```

try it, hope it would be helpful